# Unable to login H2 console in spring application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

In my spring application , I have added devtools dependency.

So, I am able to have H2 console as follows:

[image]

I haven't done any additional configuration for H2. So I expect that 'Connect' button should let me in the DB. But instead I get:

[image]

Edit: I have implemented spring security as

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/path1", "/path2")
                    .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/", "/**").access("permitAll")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login");//the path where custom login page will be provided
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like a security config issue, please share your security configs.

Comment: The security config looks fine to me, can you paste the access urls of the h2 console and whitelabel error that you are getting?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/h2-console/login.jsp?jsessionid=a00cd88ddd7a97d164a4c75588920aff,
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=a00cd88ddd7a97d164a4c75588920aff

Answer (score 1):

The page clearly shows that the error is 403 (Forbidden). Please check your  security configurations.

If you are using spring security, please check the configuration class which extends `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, there in the overridden method:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //super.configure(http);
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll() // you can allow the root endpoint ( also will be containing the default /h2-console endpoint ) for all users
                                      // or put some role restriction on the specific "/h2-console" endpoint to the admin user you are going to be logging in with.
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
          .and()
        .csrf().disable() //rest of the configs below according to your needs.
        .headers().frameOptions().disable()
          .and()
        .formLogin();
  }
```